# How can I add more username and passwords here?

Tags: bash

**The contents inside the bash file will be obfuscated**

```
echo "Enter The Login Name:"
read username
echo "Enter The Password:"
read password

if [[ $username == "user"  && $password == "password" ]]
then
  echo -e "You're Logged In\n"
elif [ $username != "user" ] 
then
  echo -e "Invalid User Name\n"
else
  echo -e "Invalid Password\n"
fi
```

Comment: Create text file with usernames and passwords. And via loop check them from file.

Comment: `while read usr pass; do <yourcommands>; done <input_file ` something like. And keep the format of your question

Comment: Please read [what will happen if you keep posting low quality content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/355310), even (or maybe especially) if you delete it later. This remark is not about the question above. It's about your answer below and about the other question. I don't think these two alone will bring you a ban right away, but you should be more careful in what you post. Turning the other question into a duplicate of this one was a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the comments says:

> Create text file with usernames and passwords. And via loop check them from file.

It's a decent idea. The code may be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function validate {
    local user pass
    while IFS=' ' read -r user pass; do
       [ "$1" = "$user" ] && [ "$2" = "$pass" ] && return 0
    done </the/file
    return 1
}

read -rp "Login: " u
read -rsp "Password: " p

echo
if validate "$u" "$p"; then
   echo "Access granted."
else
   echo "Access denied."
fi
```

Example `/the/file`:

```
kamil foo
joe bar
anotherUser pa$$word
bill password that contains spaces
```

Everything after the first space in a line is the password.

Notes:

- This could be done without a function. The function is quite useful here because of its ability to `return 0` (success) from the middle of the loop without additional logic.
- An empty line means empty login and empty password. Note in *nix every line in a text file should end with a newline character, so a newline character at the very end of the file doesn't mean there is an empty line after it. Still it's quite easy to put a truly empty line at the end so pay attention. Alternatively you can add some logic to the function so empty login will never be accepted.
- To run this code without errors, you need to have read access to `/the/file`. But if you do, you can just read the file and know all secrets. I won't fix this here. Storing passwords in a secure manner is beyond the scope of the question.
- If you prefer to embed passwords in the shell file itself then use *here document*. Instead of `done </the/file` do like:

  ```
     done <<'EOF'
  kamil foo
  joe bar
  anotherUser pa$$word
  bill password that contains spaces
  EOF
  ```

  Note quoting the first `EOF` is important. Without it `$$` would be expanded.

Comment: sir isn't there any way to accept more usernames in this case(script) I don't want to read the contents from an external human readable file(the shell will be minicated)

Comment: @PUBGHACKER See the last note in the answer. Asking for clarification is OK; adding requirements – not so much. All your requirements should be stated in the question body. At the same time you shouldn't substantially change the question *after* someone answers. A title plus code hardly ever makes a good question. In the future be more descriptive: problem, requirements, errors (if any), context maybe. A situation where the answerer (all answerers) agrees to adjust their answer should be treated as an exception, not counted on in advance. More specific problem may require a separate question.

Comment: Throws the following exception : $ bash ha.sh
Login: kamil
Password:
ha.sh: line 8: kamil: command not found
ha.sh: line 9: joe: command not found
ha.sh: line 10: EOF: command not found
Access denied.
$

Comment: @PUBGHACKER There was a typo: `<<<` where it should be `<<`. Fixed now.

Comment: THANKS THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED NOW

Comment: Can you help me in this issue also : https://superuser.com/questions/1523198/is-there-a-better-way-to-clean-logs-while-an-application-runs